# Powershell return different results running the same script from c#

Tags: c#, powershell, shell, file, attributes

I am trying to run a simple script for getting file attributes.

```
string script = @"$path = 'C:\Temp\Indexing\Asm1.asm'
                            $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
                            $folder = Split-Path $path
                            $file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
                            $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
                            $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)                           
                            0..500 | Foreach-Object { '{0} = {1}' -f $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_), $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $_).toString()}";


Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

When running within powershell I get more attribute results which are empty when running it through the code.
It seems like an access issue.
any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `#!/usr/bin/env pwsh` as first line of the script.

Comment: My only other guess would be to check with `$env:UserName` as what user the script is run.. Maybe that leads you in the right direction..